# Unexpected Error with ipynb file in VSCode

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, jupyter, ipynb

I got this error when I try to open my .ipynb file in vscode: The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unexpected token '<', ..." plt\n", <<<<<<< HE"... is not valid JSON

I have another .ipynb file and it works as usual
I google it but nothing. Do you know what it could be?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlfjX.png)
[error1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/elxbH.png)

I tried to open an .ipynb file in vscode but it doesn't work

Comment: You've stored the file in git and it has an unresolved merge conflict, that'll need manually resolved

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)